# what is the German/Austrian nomenclature(Voltage and current direction) in electronic circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, electricity, electrical, symbol, terminology

AS I came from a country where we use the french system in defining the voltage current arrows in electronic circuit, I am confused about the German/Austrian system where I see the voltage arrow is directed from positive to negative and this makes me confused when it comes to analyse complex circuit especially with diodes and mosfet. any clarification is more than welcome
[image]

here one of the circuit if I use the German Terminology
[image]

Comment: Can you add pictures of examples? Everyone uses the same polarity symbols and + is always a higher potential than -.

Comment: I have noticed also the current flows in from a generator meanwhile in french system the current comes from a generator and the current and voltage have same direction. in the load, the french system is that current and voltage are in opposite direction

Comment: That is very strange. The capacitors are polarised so + is the top. Vin should be pointing up as should Vout. VL *could* be as shown at the instant the switch is opened. It looks like a boosting power supply.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I do the same and I never been confused.but, since I am working with my Professor I have to adapt to their system.

Comment: Can you add some more context? What book does this come from and what text is around it?

Comment: The tip of the voltage arrow is in the direction of the Electric field from plus to minus. The arrowhead on the "negative" side.

Comment: German nomenclature uses **U** instead of *V* for voltage identifiers to avoid confusion with the unit symbol *V*. Also, the symbols for voltage sources and current sources are different, maybe it's that? For a source, current and voltage arrows have the opposite direction, so P=U*I is "negative". That means power is flowing **out** of a generator if U and I are positive.

Comment: Also, maybe your professor chose by purpose the so called *Verbraucherzählpfeilsystem*. There's only *Verbraucher* (loads) in there, so generators show negative power values. That's also common because you don't have to look at the schematic then. It's simply **Verbraucherzählpfeilsystem** noted somewhere prominent and that's it.

Comment: Could you explain where your confusion comes from? Direction of arrows is just a convention and just changes the sign of voltage/current in any equation.

Comment: Unfortunatly I have only his lectures. I will look up some the books and let you know after a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you stumbled over a convention called **Verbraucherzählpfeilsystem**. It's pretty common in German EE conventions.

All items are treated as loads, regardless if they are loads (*Verbraucher*) or generators.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ9SL6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This idea is you don't have to put the arrows on the schematic. You simply write *Verbraucherzählpfeilsystem* somewhere prominent, then write

$$I_g = -100A$$
$$I_l = 100A$$
$$U_g = U_l = 100V$$

and everyone agrees \$I_g\$ and \$U_g\$ belong to a generator, because \$I_g\cdot U_g\$ is negative.

You could also write **Generatorzählpfeilsystem** somewhere and use the exactly opposite definition. But that's not so common in German EE.

---

Also note German convention is using **U** instead of *V* for voltage identifiers to avoid confusion with the *V* unit symbol.

Comment: Yes, exactly but how can you figure out where the current is flowing when it comes for example a circuit with diodes and transistor as I edited it on the post.

Comment: Diodes and transistors are loads. Assume the current direction as positive in which the element is meant to conduct to fulfill its role in the circuit.