# Current through the capacitor at t=0

Tags: circuit-analysis

**DO NOT edit or rollback this question**

There have been multiple rollbacks and misunderstandings and some vandalism. Please keave as is for now and we'll to sort things out.
Major obstruction of this intent may lead to removal of some comments or answers - hopefully not.

I'm taking the unusual step of putting the following comment IN the question. This will be removed as soon as possible, but is done to stop any act-first, read the comments later actions.

The original question confused many people because the OP used a sign convention for voltage which was foreign to most site users. While the convention IS consistent with SOME European standards it is not in common use by users of this site or most EE's.
ie THIS was the cause of confusion - standards not meeting usual expectations:

[image]

Most answers were affected by this misunderstanding.
The reason has now been clarified.
Answer owners can comment if desired that the OP's sign convention was unconventional.

I have added notes in **[[double square brackets]]** showing what happened when.

I consider that this extreme action is worthwhile as there are excellent lessons to learn here. Amongst others are that questions should attempt to establish meaning as much as possible, and that answerers should be wary of being mislead by technically correct but misleading symbology.

I imagine that a good Meta question will arise from this.

____________      QUESTION  _______________

Does anybody know what is the current  `i` at `t=0`? My solution: `i(0)=-1A` since the capacitor at `t=0` is a short circuit (it was not charged at the beginning). Is that correct?

**[[Original diagram]]**

[image]

---

**Added. RM:**

Note that the arrow convention on the voltage sources is assumed by most electrical engineers to mean the following:

**[[This is what most EE's would assume the voltage polarity was, even though the arrow symbols are a European standard meaning the opposite.]]**

[image]

**[[This is the DIN EN 60617-2 standard that the OP based his question on]]**

Edit: See the definition of my voltage source I used in my hand drawn circuit:
[image]

---

Edit: I simulated this problem. There you can see that the current through the capacitor at `t=0` is `-1A` immediately after the switch has been closed. See the screenshots below.

**[[This image is based on the DIN standard polarity]]**

[image]
Simulation by https://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: By the way there is a circuit tool that you can use to draw circuits

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: Marco, with your edit you have single-handedly caused my answer to appear wrong. Your addition is clearly incorrect yet my answer said you had the magnitude correct. I'm rolling back your answer and take a very big note here: Once a question has been answered, do not modify your question without thinking about the ramifications it causes downstream to already-given answers.

Comment: How many times have you asked this question?

Comment: Andy what was incorrect of my addition? I do not understand. I only added my way of solution.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer any edit of a question should pay heed to the answers given so, if you want to reinstall your picture please do so by clearly stating that the modification is added prior to my answer being given. Another problem is that the 1.5 amps you have shown is in the wrong direction so, if you want to post something that is clearly wrong then that's up to you but, every time a question gets amended, there is a significant chance that you invalidate answers already given. My "Yes it is" will be seen as affirmation that your addition is correct and, as explained, it isn't correct.

Comment: Hence, my affirmation will be seen as wrong and attract downvotes whereas, if you didn't make that amendment, my answer is fine. Hence, be very careful in amending.

Comment: Ok Andy thanks for explaining. Now, that the question is the original one with the original circuit: Is the current +1A (plus 1A) or -1A (minus 1A)? I am a little bit confused now :)

Comment: I think this is a terrible problem and I don’t think it’s answerable. First of all, they ask for the current through the capacitor at time t=0 for a step input voltage. But a step is not defined for t=0. Secondly, the left terminal of the capacitor is floating for t<0 while the right terminal is at 100 V. So the initial capacitor voltage is undeterminable, hence the zero-input response is also undeterminable.

Comment: @Carl: I do not see any voltage drop at t=0. The voltage over the capacitor is still 0V at t=0 immediately after the switch has been closed. secondly the voltage on the left terminal is the same as on the right terminal since the voltage drop is 0V at t=0. By the way, I simulated this problem and I got i(t=0)=-1A.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer your added simulation has flipped the voltage sources and that means you get the right magnitude of current but in the wrong direction. The answer you accepted has also got the voltage sources flipped.

Comment: @Andyaka you mean my simulation has flipped both voltage sources compared to my handdrawn circuit? Now, I am again confused.

Comment: I'm not sure why this should confuse you. Your original circuit had both sources connected via their positive terminals (arrow pointing down) whereas your simulation has the batteries with negative at the lower position (short bar = negative; wide bar = positive). You should consider who is telling you the truth here.

Comment: I understand completely what you are writing. So both voltages sources in handwritten circuit and simulation are in the same direction. Right? The only difference is the symbol.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer no they are not in the same direction. Please start your comments with `@Andyaka` if I am to be notified.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for reply again. I thought that the voltage source symbol I used in my hand drawn circuit is clearly defined according to European standard? I added the definition of that symbol in my question above. You can see that is the other way around as you say. So, + (plus) above and - (minus) below. BR marco

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer that is incorrect; the arrow head points at the positive end.

Comment: @Andyaka may I ask you from where do have this information? Because Maybe in your country or continent is different? I have this information from here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spannungsquelle#/media/Datei:Quelle_U-Schaltzeichen.svg  in this way I leaned it in High School in Germany.

Comment: [Image of voltage sources](https://ka-perseus-images.s3.amazonaws.com/c8a1ab335e6d973a93de075d93b8caf3c383c86a.svg) from [this site](https://spinningnumbers.org/drafts/8-5sign-convention-sources.html). Quote: *The label on a voltage source is usually oriented with the polarity arrow going in the same direction as the actual voltage generated by the source (1a.), but there is no law that says it has to* <-- you have chosen the non-standard way.

Comment: @Andyaka ok I see. But can we then bring my question to a final state? Is it ok for you when I bring my question to the original one with the addition + (plus above) and - (minus below) symbol on the voltage sources in my hand drawn circuit? BR

Comment: No, it isn't because then it contradicts my answer. Live with it is my advice. I've taken enough downvotes on this Q and A not to want any more hassle. Leave it as it is.

Comment: I'm rolling back your question to how it was when I answered it because at the moment it suggests that I should have used your definition of what the arrow means despite most engineers believing the opposite. There is no way of fixing this that doesn't contradict one answer or the other hence, it's back to the original. Don't mess with it is my advice.

Comment: @Andyaka I edit my question. Hope it clear now. BR

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer **NO** that is not what you should do. Your latest change contradicted my answer and made it and me look inept. Redefining how you view a voltage source against all the weight of evidence to the contrary invalidates my answer. Your claim that your definition of the arrow is contrary to what this site uses. I have flagged your question to moderators so that it can be locked. I have also rolled it back to the original version.

Comment: I suggest that if you want any form of guidance on what your voltage source means, you should ask a new question that focusses only on what the arrow can be assumed to mean in the absence of polarity indicators.

Comment: @Andyaka what you maybe mean is the elctromagnetic force. I do not understand why I can not add plus and minus symbol on the voltage sources as it is defined as european standard. i dont understand the problem here. i mean it is only a symbol.

Comment: @Andyaka here is a German engineers paper from a university: https://gpr.physik.hu-berlin.de/Skripten/Einfuehrungspraktikum/PDF-Dateien/E8.pdf  you can see that they use the voltage source according to european standard. if you learned that different thats ok. as i said its not my definition. its the definition of the european standard DIN EN 60617-2.

Comment: Raise a new question to get this resolved. If the consensus is that I wrongly interpreted what you showed then I'll gladly delete my answer. This is an English speaking site and the rules pertaining to English speaking countries regarding voltage symbols will take precedence here IMHO @MarcoMoldenhauer

Comment: @Andyaka the symbol I used is unique. polarity is defined. you sent me a different symbol (a circle with a plus and minus inside). That was not the symbol I used. Thus, you did not replied related to my drawing. I do not need a new question. For me it is clear. And where is it written that must use symbols used in English speaking coutries?

Comment: I’m closing and reopening this question because rollback affected validity of VTC flags

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, let's solve and show this mathematically. We are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9noXb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, we can \$(2)\$ and substitute that into \$(1)\$:

$$\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_3}\tag3$$

Solving for \$\text{I}_3\$ we get:

$$\text{I}_3=\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{b}}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}\tag4$$

> You defined the current the other way around but the same method applies.

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)) the fact that the resistor \$\text{R}_3\$ is replaced by a capacitor and \$\$ and \$\$ are stable DC-voltages, so:

- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag5$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{a}=\frac{\text{a}}{\text{s}}\tag6$$
- $$\text{V}_\text{b}=\frac{\text{b}}{\text{s}}\tag7$$

So, we for \$\text{i}_3\$:

$$\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{C}\left(\text{a}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)-\text{R}_2\text{b}\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{s}\right)+\text{R}_2}\tag8$$

Now, getting the [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_theorem) gives:

$$\lim_{t\space\to\space0}\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\lim_{\text{s}\space\to\space\infty}\text{s}\cdot\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{a}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)-\text{b}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\tag9$$

> Using your values you find the correct answer \$1\space\text{A}\$.

Comment: There is no op amp in this circuit, so we don't need to assume it's ideal.  Presumably, you don't mean "op amp"

Comment: @ScottSeidman sorry, my mistake. Edited it, thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Hello @JanEerland, thanks for your effort. Finally the direction of the current i3(t=0) you are assuming in your circuit goes from left to right through the capacitor. In your case it is positive. So, i3(t=0)=1A (positive 1 Ampere), right?

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer yes indeed.

Comment: This isn't correct.  Only one of the voltages is a step function, the other is a constant -- so one of the transforms is wrong.

Comment: @ScottSeidman correct. If you analyze that using the method I described above you will find the exact same answer. So, do the math before you put the -1. Thanks

Comment: @JanEerland: I have a question regarding Equation (6). Do you mean Va/s instead of a/s? Same question for Equation (7). THX and BR

Comment: OK what are the downvotes for? Can anyone suggest why anyone would think my answer is incorrect?

Answer (score -2):

> *Is that correct?*

Yes it is but, current is in the direction of the arrow (i.e. flowing from a less negative voltage on the right to a more negative voltage on the left): -

[image]

And clearly, 50 volts across 50 Ω is 1 amp at the instant the switch closes.

---

What I did with the -200 volt source used Thevenin's theorem: -

[image]

Then the voltage sources can be combined to 1 source as per this: -

[image]

[Link to HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html) and please don't go downvoting willy-nilly without thinking first.

Comment: Hello Andy thanks a lot. But it is -1A (minus 1A), since my assumption of the direction in the circuit above was from right to left, right?

Comment: No, the current is in the direction of the arrow. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Hey Andy thx again, I've amended my question. There you can find my way of solution. Where is my mistake. I still get -1A (minus 1A). HEEELP :)

Comment: Hey Andy again, how did you simplify the circuit. I do not understand

Comment: Huh?  The voltage between the two resistors is 100V at t=0 (zero minus),  The switch closes and then you have 150v on the left side of the cap and 100V on the right -- no??

Comment: @ScottSeidman I believe the arrows on the voltage sources indicate that their negative terminals are on the top. It's that 'too many different ways of drawing things' problem again.

Comment: @GodJihyo  This is one of the issues, but before the switch closes, there's either 100V or -100V sitting on the right side of the cap.  The instant the switch closes, there's going to be plus or minus 50V sitting across the cap (with the direction depending on whatever the sign convention was!), vs whatever the initial condition was.

Comment: Hello all, please note that this is a simplified circuit from @Andyaka. I do not know how he derive this circuit. Please use the original circuit in my original question as reference.

Comment: OK what are the downvotes for? Can anyone suggest why anyone would think my answer is incorrect?

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer it's called thevenin's equivalent circuit. You take the 200 volt source and the two 100 ohm resistors and make an equivalent source that is 100 volts in series with 50 ohm. Marco, did you downvote me?

Comment: @Andyaka, ok thx! I still can not vote. I am very new here.

Comment: @ScottSeidman no you are getting into a muddle here. The voltage difference prior to the switch closing is 50 volts because the -200 volt source is, in effect 100 volts in series with 50 ohms.

Comment: @Andyaka: I still do not understand how you derive the alternative circuit with thevenin theorem.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer look at the linked picture in my answer. Do you not understand the formula presented? If you ignored R2 (which doesn't exist in your circuit), can you see that the equivalent resistance is \$\frac{R1\cdot R3}{R1+R3}\$ and do you see that R1 = R3 = 100 ohm? Can you do the math to prove that \$r = \frac{100^2}{2\cdot 100} = 50\$? Can you see that e = 200/2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139181/discussion-between-marco-moldenhauer-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Hello @Andyaka The formula I understand which are shown in the picture. But the problem is that I am not sure if I understand the theorem correctly. For example ist that true: A=A‘ and B=B‘? Best Regards

Comment: Hello @Andyaka again :), I edited my question again. hope this is ok. I added a screenshot of a simulation: https://tinyurl.com/2eo3ysqe her I got also -1A (minus 1A).

Comment: **YELL MODE ON** :-) - Andy's solution at the time I'm reading it is correct. It does not deserve the 3 downvotes that it has. These may be a result of people misunderstanding several basic but subtle points to the question. || The voltage sources polarity is inobvious but the arrows suggest positive is "down". || The 200V source and two x 100 ohm resistors can be transformed to a single 100V source with 50 ohm series resistor, as Andy has shown. || If you do not think these points are correct then you need to read the answer more closely.

Comment: ... || Current sign depends on the ambiguous voltage sign convention. || The question cannot be answered sensibly without assuming that the capacitor is discharged at t=0.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: thanks for reply. I guess the solution of Andyaka was 1A from right to left through the capacitor. But the simulation shows 1A from left to right.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer As above, you have to decide what the sign convention is for voltage. The original diagram has arrows with heads pointing downwards - which most electrical engineers would take to mean that V+ was down and V- up. BUT your simulation has V+ up in each case. Andy has used the V+ down convention which the original diagram appears to show - so his answer is opposite that shown in the simulation. We cannot be sure what the original writers intended but Andy's interpretation is more normal.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Ahhhhhh ok now it is clear (I guess) :) Andy was flipping the 200V voltage source the other way around. Is that allowed? THX and BR

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer It's worse that that :-). YOU were flipping both voltage sources realtive to the original IF the arrow show positive is downwards. Andy is assuming positive down is what's intended and acting accordingly.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer I have not flipped any voltage sources. As originally drawn in your first diagram, both voltages have positive on their lower terminal and negative on their upper terminal. In your added simulation you have also failed to recognize that. The current is 1 amp flowing right to left as I keep saying. Any other answer is wrong including the one you have accepted; it shows voltage sources flipped.

Comment: @Andyaka He has not yet grasped that the down pointing arrow on the voltage sources *probably* signifies positive grounded supplies. I've explained that but it's not intuitive.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer This sort of confusion is easiy to happen and can be hard to put right. Please read my explanations above again carefully - the diagrams are drawn in a strange way and the polarity convention used is not 100% obvious. In the original hand drawn diagram in the question the downward pointing arrows indicate (probably) that the voltage sources are "flipped" compared to usual usage. This means that their positive terminals are grounded. Andy has used that convention throughout his answer. In your simulation you have "flipped" the supplies compared to your hand drawn diagram.

Comment: In some countries, the voltage arrow "tip" does not indicate the "positive terminal". But the negative terminal. Because the voltage arrow shows the E-field direction. Thus, we have a positive voltage, not a negative one as was shown in Andy's diagrams.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/407316/what-is-the-german-austrian-nomenclaturevoltage-and-current-direction-in-elect

Comment: @G36 I've asked the op to raise a new question on this subject so it can be adequately resolved by the folk here. If some countries use the opposite notation to what is used in the US or UK or NZ then this is important to get out in the open.

Comment: It looks like a German standard to my https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spannungsquelle 
The tip of the voltage arrow is in the direction of the Electric field from plus to minus.

Comment: @G36 yet I have this: https://ka-perseus-images.s3.amazonaws.com/c8a1ab335e6d973a93de075d93b8caf3c383c86a.svg from [here](https://spinningnumbers.org/drafts/8-5sign-convention-sources.html). Anyway, it ought to be a new question.

Comment: But TS is from Switzerland so for sure he is using a German standard. Look at the voltage source symbol. Not the symbol "we" use to use.

Comment: @G36 thx! you are right I am using German standard symbol according to standard DIN EN 60617-2. next time i remember that and i will add + and - on the voltage sources. I